# How to get first specific value in json object using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I like to know how i can get first specific value in a json like

```
$.each(data, function(i, val){
    console.log(val.name);
});
```

sample output of above code is like this

```
John
Mary
Kite
```

but i like to get only first value like this

```
John
```

Comment: What data type is `data`? Object or array

Comment: If it's not an Array, then there is no "first" since objects are unordered.

Comment: You ***may*** be able to get the first that is defined in the original JSON string if you use `JSON.parse()` and pass it a "reviver" function. I *think* it'll give you the properties you encounter in order, though it'll traverse into a nested object before giving you the key for that object.

Comment: ...other than that, if all you need is the first property of the object, then you could parse it yourself just up to that point, and then `JSON.parse()` it, and use the property you found to grab the first.,

Answer (score 5):

If `data` is an array, you can do

```
name=data[0].name
```

If it's an object, it's slightly more complicated

```
name=data[Object.keys(data)[0]].name;
```

Keep in mind that object keys aren't really sorted in any particular order

Comment: The `Object.keys` approach won't guarantee any particular item as the "first" item. ... *"...object keys aren't really sorted except for the order you put it in."* No, there is no order. The order you give guarantees nothing.

Comment: @cookiemonster I thought that if you put three properties in an object like `obj={foo:"bar",baz:"qux"}`, this will give `foo` first

Comment: @scrblnrd3: No, there are no guarantees as to the order. That goes for `for-in` as well as `Object.keys`. Different browsers may behave differently. The same browser may even behave differently in different situations.

Comment: Could you give an example please?

Comment: @scrblnrd3: I'm describing how it's defined in the ECMAScript specification. If you look at the spec for `Object.keys`, you'll see that it instructs to use the same iteration as defined for `for-in` (if any). If you look at `for-in`, you'll see that the ordering is entirely implementation dependent. Even if we were to find entirely consistent behavior across all browsers today, that could change with the next update. There are simply no guarantees.

Comment: It's specified partially here [sec-12.6.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4) -- "The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties is not specified" -- and probably somewhere else.

Comment: You're welcome. In the Go language, it's a similar situation, but the implementations generally (or maybe it's required by the spec) shuffle the order intentionally so that people don't suffer from an illusion of a guaranteed order. Would be good if JS implementations did the same IMO.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the structure of the json object but it should look  like this:

```
data[0].name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return `false` from the iteration function, `$.each()` terminates the loop. So you can simply return `false` the first time:

```
$.each(data, function(i, val){
    console.log(val.name);
    return false;
});
```

Since object elements don't have any inherent order, there's no guarantee this will print a specific name. It will just pick one of the names arbitrarily.